# Filtering by column in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, filter

I have trouble filtering by `skin_color` that contains the word "green" in the Star Wars API.
Also Im grouping it by unique `hair_color`
For now i have:

```
library(dplyr)
sw<-starwars
sw %>%
  filter(skin_color=="green")%>%
    group_by(hair_color) %>%
        count(hair_color) %>%
          setNames(c("Color","Count"))-> swG
```

I am sure it has to do something with regex, but i can't figure it out.

Comment: What's your actual question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to filter the skin_color column so that I get every record that contains the word green so for eg. green-tan or mottled-green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter all green skin_color use `grepl`

```
sw<-starwars
sw %>%
  filter(grepl('green', skin_color)) %>% 
  group_by(hair_color) %>%
  count(hair_color) %>%
  setNames(c("Color","Count"))-> swG
swG
```

Output:

```
  Color  Count
  <chr>  <int>
1 blonde     1
2 none       7
3 white      1
4 NA         2
```

Comment: That was indeed what I was searching for. Thank you

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, i will try to form them better next time :)